# Visual Studio: edit xaml while debugging (without stopping debugging)

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've got the very same problem as this question: [Edit Xaml while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3336213/7021) with a twist.

My debug session usually runs some code while I need to change stuff in the XAML, and if I detach all, as recommended as answer in that question, the debugged program might run on, but the WCF services which are also hosted in the debugger will be stopped immediately.

And without service my programm usually last mere seconds.

So, is there a way to exit xaml files during debugging? I don't care for debug and continue, I'm aware the changes will take effect only after a restart of the app. I just need to type in some stuff so I won't forget and am annoyed that I have to use an external editor instead of VS.

Comment: Seems like an oversight by M$.  Edit and continue is off, so can edit other code files, just not xaml...such a pain

Answer (score 1):

I always use another tool. Like notepad++ or expression blend.

You can configure this by right clicking the file -> open with. Or with expression blend you get the open in expression blend option and its pretty good for xaml anyways.

Answer (score 0):

if you need dynamic build you can take a look at [project Roslyn](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27746)

more info [here](http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/microsoft-previews-compiler-service-software-173207)

"Developers could also use the output of such software to do tasks like refactor, or reorganize, their code more easily, to add C# and Visual Basic functionality to programs written in other languages. It also adds dynamic typing to the statically typed C# and Visual Basic, allowing developers to add objects and new variables to a program on the fly."

Comment: No need for dynamic build. I just want to change code while the app is running, but it does not need to reflect in the app until it is recompiled.